# How many Complete Graph present in given undirected Graph?

Tags: graph, subgraph

Is there a known algorithm to  find all complete sub-graphs within a graph? I have an undirected, graph and I need to find all complete graphs present in that undirected graph.

Is there an existing algorithm for this?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the number of complete subgraphs in an undirected graph is known as the *clique problem*. It is not solvable in polynomial time, since the number of complete subgraphs itself might be exponential. Therefore, there is not an algorithm that will solve this for graphs of any size in a reasonable amount of time. However, here is one I found that should work for small graphs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm